# Is it not possible to change styles through JS in React Native?

Tags: react-native

Can't RN do style changes using JS?

```
...
const PR = PanResponder.create({
    onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (e, gestureState) => true,
    onPanResponderStart: (e, gestureState) => {
      console.log("start");
    },
    onPanResponderMove: (e, gestureState) => {
      const dx = Math.abs(gestureState.dx);
      **target.current.style.backgroundColor** = `rgba(${dx},${dx / 2},106,1)`;
    },
    onPanResponderEnd: (e, gestureState) => {
      const dx = Math.abs(gestureState.dx);
      if (!dx) {
        target.current.style.backgroundColor = "green";
      }
      console.log("End");
    },
  });
...
```

As above, it is difficult to change the style on mobile.
Thank you for your reply.

The useState hook was not what I was expecting.

help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code above it looks like you were storing the style with `useRef`, which doesnt trigger component updates when its value changes. Here's a useState [example](https://snack.expo.dev/JnSlfmGM5)

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, PanResponder } from 'react-native';
import Animated, {
  useSharedValue,
  interpolateColor,
} from 'react-native-reanimated';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

export default function App() {
  const [style, setStyle] = React.useState({
    borderWidth: 1,
    width: '100%',
    height: 280,
    backgroundColor: 'lightgreen',
  });
  const PR = PanResponder.create({
    onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (e, gestureState) => true,
    onPanResponderStart: (e, gestureState) => {
      console.log('start');
    },
    onPanResponderMove: (e, gestureState) => {
      const dx = Math.abs(gestureState.dx);
      console.log(dx);
      setStyle((prev) => ({
        ...prev,
        backgroundColor: `rgba(${dx},${dx / 2},106,1)`,
      }));
    },
    onPanResponderEnd: (e, gestureState) => {
      const dx = Math.abs(gestureState.dx);
      console.log(dx);
      if (!dx) {
        setStyle((prev) => ({ ...prev, backgroundColor: 'green' }));
      }
      console.log('End');
    },
  });
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={style} {...PR.panHandlers} />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```

While it works, the best results would come from using Animated.View and some Animated values

Comment: Your answer helped me a lot.
thank you

 I know that useRef can be used to manipulate the style of an RN element. But I don't know if this method is only possible on the web.

still,

Your answer has been a great learning opportunity for me.

thank you

Comment: My understanding of useRef is that it doesn’t trigger component updates when it’s value changes.  I think the react elements do something special under the hood to register these style updates you mention, although I could be wrong. I haven’t really dug that deeply into react web so yeahhhhu

Answer (score 0):

Look into this [panResponder](https://www.tabnine.com/code/javascript/classes/react-native/PanResponderGestureState) . It has some example of how to use
PanResponderGestureState
in
react-native